# HTML banner with click Tag but in validator it says it's missing

Tags: javascript, html, validation, jquery-animate, banner

I have tried everything with my HTML banner that I created with Adobe Animate. With the "add using wizard" option inactions, my banner works perfectly - when clicking on a button it opens a webpage. But the HTML validator says that it's missing a click Tag so I put the code below in the HTML file, but it still says click tag is missing, and I'm afraid that when my client use Ad Manager they will get this fault too.

```
<head>
  <meta name="ad.size" content="width=160,height=600">
  <script>
    var clickTag = "http://myclientswebpage.com";
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();" style="margin:0px;">
  <a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)"> <canvas id="canvas" width="160" height="600" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color:rgba(35, 31, 32, 1.00);"></canvas></a>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082953/google-web-designer-banner-missing-click-tag-check-on-validation

Answer (score 0):

this should work:
(notice the clickTag - is without window and i added void)

```
<head>
  <meta name="ad.size" content="width=160,height=600">
  <script>
    var clickTag = "http://myclientswebpage.com";
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();" style="margin:0px;">
  <a href="javascript:void(window.open(clickTag))"> <canvas id="canvas" width="160" height="600" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color:rgba(35, 31, 32, 1.00);"></canvas></a>


</body>
```

Comment: Please let me know if this answer fixed your error

Comment: Hey Elnatan, thank you for the answer, unfortunately it still says "missing click tag" in the h5 validator...

Comment: weird it should work, i dont know why you are getting this error.. did youtry to check it with different validator?

Comment: i tried this one https://h5validator.appspot.com/adwords/asset and there is no faults, don't know which one is the right one to use though

Comment: you said on your question " But the HTML validator says that it's missing a click Tag" which validator gave this error?

Comment: this might help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405105/missing-click-tag-despite-google-ad-manager-tap-area-exit-event check the answer there. how the set the envierment

Comment: I used this one: https://h5validator.appspot.com/dcm/asset. The link you send is for google web designer and i used Adobe animate